# How to have an URL in PDF bookmark

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls, bookmarks

I'm interested in having a PDF **bookmark pointing to an attached file in the PDF**.
At least I know it is possible to have bookmarks pointing to an URL. See for instance [the `hyperref` manual](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf).
You can see that the last bookmarks are pointing to other PDF in the Internet.

If it is not possible to have a bookmark pointing to an attached file in the PDF file, how did they manage to have a bookmark pointing to an URL?

Comment: Package [`bookmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) supports URL actions, see option `uri`.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!! :) Both answers were really helpful!
It totally worked! I should have found this site while completing my MSc Thesis a few years ago...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `hypgotoe` add support for embedded go-to actions (`GoToE`) to `\href`. This action type only works from and to PDF files. The package only supports destination names as link targets. For example they can be set via `\hypertarget` or extracted by package `zref-xr` or `xr-hyper`.

More arbitrary bookmarks can be generated via package `bookmark`. Currently it does not support `GoToE` actions, but it has an options `rawaction`, that allows to specify the raw PDF action dictionary for unsupported actions.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypgotoe}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
\embedfile{t.pdf}

\href{gotoe:embedded=t.pdf,dest=page.2}{Page 2 of \texttt{t.pdf}}

\bookmark[   
  rawaction={
    /S /GoToE    % action type
    /D (page.2)  % destination name
    /D [0 /FitH 750] %
    /T <<
      /R /C      % relation: child
      /N (t.pdf) % name of embedded file
    >>
  },
]{Embedded file t.pdf, page 2}

\bookmark[   
  rawaction={
    /S /GoToE    % action type
    /D [0 /FitH 700] % go to first page,
                     % view: fit width at 750bp from the bottom
    /T <<
      /R /C      % relation: child
      /N (t.pdf) % name of embedded file
    >>
  },
]{Embedded file t.pdf, page 1}

\end{document}
```

`t.pdf` was generated from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Embedded file}
\newpage
Page two of embedded file.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)'s `uri` key-value supports hyperlinking to *external* content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\bookmark[uri={http://tex.stackexchange.com},color=blue,startatroot]{TeX.SE}

\end{document}
```